# Tango SDK Android API Support Level

Tags: google-project-tango

In Tango SDK Ikariotikos version, android:targetSdkVersion is 23.

If you build with Android Level 24, "Unable to load Tango library. Things may not work." Log is created and Tango Service is not connected.

Does the Tango SDK support Android 7.0 Nougat (API level 24)?

Answer me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to check Tango Core is installed ! 
There are 2 required apps with 'Tango' name.